# Dependencies inside an object

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have this code

```
class Duck {
  protected $strVocabulary;
  public function Learn() {
   $this->strVocabulary = 'quack';
  }

  public function Quack() {
   echo $this->strVocabulary;
  }
}
```

The code is in PHP but the question is not PHP dependent.
Before it knows to Quack a duck has to Learn.

My question is: How do I make `Quack()` invokable only after `Learn()` has been called?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The two functions are not dependent on each other, if that's what you're thinking. They both modify `$strVocabulary`, but they're not interdependent.

Comment: @Jonathan from a functionality point of view they work separately but from a logical point a view you first have to call learn then quack to get some valid results.

Comment: So is your question, "How do I make Quack invokable *only* after Learn has been called?" or are you just saying this is your structure and you'll manage the order of method invocation in your code?

Comment: @Jonathan - yes ("How do I make Quack invokable only after Learn has been called"). Also I was thinking of design patterns and if this case has any correlations with one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that does not violate any OOP principle.

A prominent example is an object who's behavior depends on whether a connection is established or not (e.g. function `doNetworkStuff()` depends on `openConnection()`).

In Java, there is even a [typestate checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#typestate-checker), which performs such checks (whether `Duck` can already `Quack()`) at compile time. I often have such dependencies as preconditions for interfaces, and use a forwarding class whose sole purpose is protocolling and checking the state of the object it forwards to, i.e. protocol which functions have been called on the object, and throw exceptions (e.g.  InvalidStateException) when the preconditions are not met.

A design pattern that handles this is [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern): It allows an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class. The [design pattern book from the Gang of Four](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) also uses the example above of a network connection either being established or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the order then you can use an abstract base class where in the function quack() you call learn() first and then abstract method doquack() (some other good name, and this will have to be implemented by each derived class).

Comment: That is a nice solution if the object can control its state independently. It does not work if a client or the environment controls the state.

Comment: I agree. I'd go with state in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: How do I make Quack() invokable only after Learn() has
>   been called?

you can separate concerns:

```
class EnrolleeDuck {
  public function Learn() {
   return new AlumnusDuck('quack');
  }
}

class AlumnusDuck
{
  protected $strVocabulary;

  public function __construct(&strVocabulary) {
    &this->strVocabulary = &strVocabulary;
  }

  public function Quack() {
   echo $this->strVocabulary;
  }
}
```

It's my first lines in PHP, feel free to correct